# Conversejs has support to get archive message in indexedDb by plugin not?

Tags: xmpp, chat, indexeddb, converse.js

Please show me how conversejs can get the message stored in indexedDb by plugin if possible? I want to create my own chat history list interface because controlbox is not suitable for my business.

Answer (score 0):

The messages are stored in a [Collection](https://backbonejs.org/#Collection) which is set as the `messages` attribute on the `ChatBox` model. A ChatBox represents the Chat conversation with a particular contact.

```
converse.plugins.add("my-plugin", {
  
  initialize() {
    const { api } = this._converse;
    const chat = api.chats.get('contact@example.org');

    // log all messages to the console
    chat.messages.forEach(m => console.log(m.get('body'));
  }

});
```